# SSIS DtsDebugHost.exe Memory Overflow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dts

I have a package that is setup to concatenate a bunch of individual values from a table, pass those values into an IN statement to then form a SQL string, then pass that string into a dataflow task that pulls data from another server. The server I am querying only allows me to pull 1k records at a time, so this process has to usually loop anywhere from 10-100 times depending on what our volume is like for the day.

Whenever I initially run the package, it performs fine. But slowly over time  the DtsDebugHost.exe *32 will gradually accumulate more and more memory usage until the package crashes. This happens both in visual studio, and in command prompt when I execute in dtexec. How can I stop DtsDebugHost.exe *32 from hogging all my memory and crashing?

Comment: So let's tease this out. You need to query the Parameters table to get all the Account numbers that need to be transferred. You concatenate all those into big strings which you then use as a filter for a query that you ultimately pass to a data flow task.  *somehow* your data flow knows it needs to run 10-100 times pulling 1k rows at a time. Somewhere along the way, SSIS throws an out of memory exception. Is that a valid restatement of the problem? Could you pop some screenshots of what your control flow + data flow look like? Maybe some sample of how the various queries are being built?

Comment: Does this package ever run outside of your computer (deployed to a server)?

Comment: Yes, that's a fair restatement. The package knows how many times to loop through based off of the table the records sit in. The table only has two columns, one with the record being passed into the IN statement, and the other which indicates whether the column has been iterated by the loop. Those indicators are initially read as a 0, then changed to a 1 as it exits the loop, so the SQL task in SSIS knows not to include those again. The package is only deployed locally. Either through visual studio, or by DTEXEC in command prompt. I will include pictures when I return to the office tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Go to task manager and kill `DtsDebughost.exe` it will solve the issue